# Escaping special character in Ruby

Tags: ruby, escaping

How can I append the string `'\x'` to a number in Ruby? I have tried `'\\x'` but it's not working.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like:

```
my_string = 'foo 123 456 bar'
my_string.gsub(/(\d+)/, '\\x\1') # "foo \\x123 \\x456 bar"
```

Comment: That's probably what OP wants, even though he said "append", not "prepend".

Answer (score 0):

Without context it's hard to know what you are trying to achieve. Here are some ways (if you really want to append):

```
"%d\\x" % num
"#{num}\\x"
```

If you are trying to output hex numbers, this is good:

```
"\\x%s" % num.to_s(16)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a single-quoted string for `'\x'` then you may already have what you want. When Ruby (or to be more accurate, IRB) prints a string with a literal backslash it shows it escaped by default, which is how `#p` behaves (that's what IRB uses to show results). But the string may only have one blackslash as desired.

```
num = 123
s = '%d\x' % num  #=> "123\\x" (using the short-hand form for sprintf)

print s #=> 123\x
p s #=> "123\\x"
puts '%d\x' % num #=> 123\x - what the string actually contains

puts num.to_s + '\x'
```

Note that in Ruby single quoted string literals undergo a lot less substitution than double-quoted ones.